# jQuery: How do I remove class based on a particular condition?

Tags: jquery, html

I am trying to remove a class based on a particular condition.

I am adding the code below for reference.

**HTML**

```
<li id="menu-item-81" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-81">
    <a href="#home" class="currentItem">
        <span class="no-color-4u small-font">HOME</span>
    </a>
</li>
```

**jQuery**

```
if (jQuery("#menu-item-81 a").hasClass("currentItem")) {
    alert('I has the class');
    jQuery('.small-font').removeClass('no-color-4u');
} else {
    alert("I don't has the class");
    jQuery('.small-font').addClass('no-color-4u');  
}
```

In this case the alerts work. But I cannot see the class of the span being removed once the class of the a tag has been detected. Can somebody please help me with this?

In the following code

```
jQuery('.small-font').removeClass('no-color-4u');
```

The class `no-color-4u` still is showing in the span tag. Even when the `#menu-item-81 a` has the `currentItem` class. Do you need anything else?

Thanks.

Comment: Editing question

Comment: Check the code snippet in my answer. Run it and then `inspect element` on HOME link, where you can see that the `<span>` do not contain the `no-color-4u ` class.

Comment: Your code looks okay and it's working. When are you doing this class check?

Comment: As others have mentioned already, your code works fine. Can you try creating a snippet in the question itself (using the `<>` button) or a jsFiddle?

Comment: Note that unless you confirm / close the `alert` message the next statement in the block of code won't run. So to see the class being removed you have to click-off the alert box. Better is to use `console.log` for debugging purposes.

Comment: @davidnoronha please review an answer this will probably save your time.

Answer (score 0):

The code which you have posted works as expected. Check if you have included the `jquery` plugin in your HTML page or not.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  if (jQuery("#menu-item-81 a").hasClass("currentItem")) {
      alert('I has the class');
      jQuery('.small-font').removeClass('no-color-4u');
  } else {
      alert("I don't has the class");
      jQuery('.small-font').addClass('no-color-4u');  
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
<li id="menu-item-81" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-81">
    <a href="#home" class="currentItem">
        <span class="no-color-4u small-font">HOME</span>
    </a>
</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: I have added the cdn you provided. It's still not working

Comment: wrap the JQuery code in `$(document).ready(function(){` and send me your entire HTML page. May be in a plunkr or jsfiddle. I will look at it.

Comment: I am trying that

Comment: I tried enclosing it in `$(document).ready(function(){` still no help. Is something conflicting?

Comment: Maybe there are other JQuery codes that conflicts with this. But the particular block of code should be working fine.

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".lnkMenu").on("click", function() {
    $(".lnkMenu").removeClass("currentItem");
    $(this).addClass("currentItem");
    $(".lnkMenu").children("span").removeClass("no-color-4u");
    $(this).children("span").addClass("no-color-4u");
  });
});
```

```css
ul, li{
  list-style:none;
}
a {
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 12px;
  font-family: arial;
  color: #000000;
}

a.currentItem {
  color: #FF0000;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li id="menu-item-81" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-81">
    <a href="#home" class="lnkMenu currentItem">
      <span class="no-color-4u small-font">Menu 1</span>
    </a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#home" class="lnkMenu">
      <span class="small-font">Menu 2</span>
    </a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#home" class="lnkMenu">
      <span class="small-font">Menu 3</span>
    </a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: How do I do this on check of the class existence in the parent?

Comment: @davidnoronha: First you should remove previous class currentItem class, children span no-color-4u class and add currentItem class for selected element and children spa no-color-4u.

Comment: @davidnoronha First is it fulfill your requirement or not and if not then let me know what other things you want

Comment: @davidnoronha always you should get the reference to the class so it will easy to manipulate and traverse in DOM.

Comment: It's working to some extent but not as per my requirement. What I want is when the Page is opened and checks if the current id is linked with the menu id which is happening. The span class should be removed.

Comment: @davidnoronha At least you should do some efforts to resolve with some update guidelines. We are trying to guide you and it will resolve your issue based on your best description of the question.

Comment: @davidnoronha which is serverside language you used?

Comment: It's PHP. Using Wordpress

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/163528/discussion-between-dipak-chavda-and-david-noronha).

Answer (score 0):

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
      if (jQuery("#menu-item-81 a .small-font").hasClass("no-color-4u")) {
          alert('I has the class');
          jQuery('.small-font').removeClass('no-color-4u');
      } else {
          alert("I don't has the class");
          jQuery('.small-font').addClass('no-color-4u');  
      }
  });
```

Comment: It has to check if the menu-item is active